# Cant install DLIB [Debian 7] [Python 2.7]

Tags: python-2.7, debian, dlib

I have problem with installing dlib. Im using debian 7 and python 2.7. Thats the full code.

Im following the steps from these guide - https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/27/how-to-install-dlib/

Full log you can find here - https://paste.ee/p/AbXxJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC 4.7 is too old.  You need a C++11 compiler.  Get a newer version of GCC.